# How to use kubeconfig as environment variable in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, azure-aks, cicd, kubeconfig

I'm creating a GitLab CI/CD pipeline to deploy an application to Azure Kubernetes Services.

1. How can I specify a kubeconfig file as environment variable?
2. How can be used in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Project/Settings/CICD/Variables section
and add a variable there with type "File"[image]

Then you can use it in the pipeline:

```
  before_script:
    - export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: Why not directly define `KUBECONFIG` instead of `KUBECONFIG_FILE`